# Cannot add search engines in IE11 on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, internet-explorer-11

What the title says. If I try to add DuckDuckGo, StartPage, etc., nothing literally happens when I click the button to add the search engine as the IE dialog asking to confirm the addition does not load.

This is occurring on a fresh installation of Windows 8.1 after applying all Windows updates. Nothing else was installed. And I am trying this on desktop IE, not Modern IE.

Comment: Does it work if you run IE as admin?

Comment: It doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: There are ways to get Google and Yahoo via the "Manage Add-Ons". But  DuckDuckGo is not an option.

Comment: That doesn't work either.

Comment: Do you have third party security software installed that protects IE?

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be an issue with the **KB3038314** update which for some fails to install and for others introduces the problem You described. Microsoft is aware of it.

It's a problem on other Windows versions as well.

If You can't wait for Microsoft to release a patch You can "fix" the problem by uninstalling that update **(not recommended):**

1. Open Installed Updates by clicking the Start button, clicking Control Panel, clicking Programs, and then, under Programs and Features, clicking View installed updates.
2. Find "Security Update for Microsoft Windows (KB3038314)" and click that update, and then click Uninstall.

[Source: How to "fix" the problem](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e9adca24-90ca-436c-aea4-655680da447a/ie-11-not-able-to-add-search-provider)

[Source: Microsoft employee reproduces the problem](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_update/kb3038314-fails-to-install-get-the-error-80092004/596a3bb5-151d-4742-8eab-420e45840077?page=21&tab=question&status=AllReplies#tabs)